# How to exclude only numbers, punctuation marks from input? Python

Tags: python

Is there any way to make a rule, where answer to the input may be only String or string+numeric value without punctuation marks/space. So that will look like.

```
Insert first name:  …
… name: 5363737 - **not allowed**
… name: Bird1 ! - **not allowed**
… name: Bird1 - **allowed**
```

Comment: Where is the `python` code? Are you wanting to validate what the user has typed or are you wanting to prohibit the user from typing specific characters?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are "inserting" with might have its own validation functions, but if not, its a straightforward regular expression to filter with.

```
import re

inserts = [
    'aBC123',
    'ABC 123',
    'i like pie.',
    '123abc',
]

for i in inserts:
    if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$', i):
#   if re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', i):   #leaving my old error visible as a testament to the importance of reading the spec carefully.
        print('insert', i)
        # call insert function
    else:
        print('NOT inserting', i)
        # do whatever
```

Comment: in about 5 minutes when you decide regular expressions are your new god, you'll want to know about this site http://www.rexv.org/

Comment: @Moontego: are you sure this code does what you want? It will match stuff like `5363737`

Comment: Nope, I used the code from @LetzerWille. This one doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies.  I was trying to get you something before I ran out the door and misread what you wanted.  @LetzerWillie got it right.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Code:

     or i in "5363737","Bird1 !", "Bird1", "Bird1923812", "Bird":

        mo = re.match(r'([A-Za-z]+[0-9]*)$',i)

        if mo:
            print("allowed {}".format(mo.group(0)))
        else:
            print("not allowed {}".format(i))

    not allowed 5363737
    not allowed Bird1 !
    allowed Bird1
    allowed Bird1923812
    allowed Bird

# if needed, as stated in the comment  char+number+char, number+char, 
# number+char+number.
for i in "536cat3737","Bird1 !", "Bird1", "Bird1923812bird", "Bird","777Bird":

    mo = re.match(r'([A-Za-z]*[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+|\d+[A-Za-z]+\d+)$',i)

    if mo:
        print("allowed {}".format(mo.group(0)))
    else:
        print("not allowed {}".format(i))
```

Comment: Hey, I used your code and it almost works. The only problem is that it is not allowing for example "Bird1923812". The rule had to be so that I can use any char+numeric value, but right now it is limited by 0-9. How can I change the regex, so it will accept all the numbers that come after a character? I tried re.match(r'([A-Za-z][\d])+$',i) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am so thankful. It does work right now. I am just in the first semester into the university and some of the homeworks are a bit too difficult :) thanks once more!

Comment: I encountered a new problem. Now it wont accept the regular "only character" input. For example "Bird" is allowed too. It doesn't have to be "Bird1, Bird12391239". So it needs to accept the regular character input too.

Comment: @Moontego Ok, take a look.

Comment: Yea, it looks like now it is finished. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Tip: use `[0-9]*` instead of `([0-9]+)?)`

Comment: I am here again. It has to accept something like: AYksadkj2139as12123sjsj too. Right now it is limited by char+number, but it may also be char+number+char, number+char, number+char+number.

Comment: @Moontego  Bird1 - **allowed** does not fit into these three cases that you wrote.

Comment: But If I tried making it vice versa and not allowing numbers ONLY, ANY special characters and spaces or blank input. I tried to make it: while re.match("[0-9][!@#$%&]$",questName): But it's not working :(

Comment: @Moontego, i can update with char+number+char, number+char, number+char+number.. no problem

Answer (score 0):

Without `re` module:

```
from string import letters, digits
from itertools import chain

while True:
    user_input = input('Insert first name: ')
    if all(c in digits for c in user_input) or #invalid if only numbers   
       any(c not in chain(letters,digits) for c in user_input): #invalid if something else than letters+numbers
        print 'name: ' + user_input + '** not allowed **'
    else:
        print 'name: ' + user_input + '** allowed **'
        break
```